# Windows 8 wont recognize my Lumia 925

Tags: sync, windows-8

Windows 8 doesn't seem to properly recognize my phone.

[image]

You can see that windows knows I have a Windows Phone device plugged in.

[image]

It shows up in Devices...

Clicking on it

[image]

Gives me this. If I open up the Windows Phone thing.

[image]

It tells me to connect my phone...

It is connected. :(

Comment: Have you restarted both the Phone and your computer?

Comment: I have. But I can try again soon. I'm just uninstalling all the software then will re-install, reboot, and reconnect.

Comment: Ahhhh, I got it working. It still wouldn't connect so I unplugged it, turned my pc off. Plugged it in and booted with it plugged in, picked it up that time and now theres no issue plugging it in etc.

Comment: @Phill you might want to post that as an answer

Comment: in case you still have this problem, just install Windows Media Feature Pack for Windows 10 or 8 or 7.. it will work like charm http://www.winbeta.org/news/grab-media-feature-pack-windows-10-n-and-windows-10-kn-editions (for windows 10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent maybe two hours getting this working. In the end I:

1. Uninstalled all software.

   - Zune
   - Windows Phone (Windows 8 App)
   - Windows Phone (Windows Desktop App)
2. Rebooted the computer with the phone not plugged in
3. Shut down the computer
4. Restarted the phone
5. Plugged it back into the computer
6. Turned the computer back on
7. Installed the Windows Phone app (Windows 8 app)

Everything worked fine after that.